# Ruby script to load .xlsx files into a MySQL database

Tags: ruby, mysql, file, excel

I put together this Ruby script (1.9.3) to load data into MySQL from many .xlsx files that contain data entered by people. These files typically have many illegal characters and it has been difficult to handle the different errors. I have tried multiple rescue and character escaping approaches but now this method is not good and I have several more in the same class that are similar but load from different formats.

I would love some code review to help make this more functional. This is a standalone Ruby script without Rails or activerecord. I am using the logger, rubyXL, and MySQL2 gems.

```
  def paid_adv_load_ppc
    begin
      Dir["#{@paid_adv_work_path}*.xlsx"].each do |file|
        if file =~ /(PPC)/ && file !~ /(~)/
          begin 
            @file = file
            begin
              workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse(file)
              data = workbook.worksheets[0]
              sheet1 = data.extract_data
              begin
                sheet1.each_with_index do |row,index|
                  if index > 0 && row[1] != nil
                    service = row[3].to_s.gsub(/['"]/, '') 
                    impressions = row[9].to_i 
                    clicks = row[10].to_i
                    cost = row[11].to_f
                    total = row[12].to_f
                    puts "index: #{index} row: #{row}"
                    @db.query("INSERT INTO ppc
                     (service,impressions,clicks,cost,total)
                     VALUES  ('#{service}',#{impressions},#{clicks},#{cost},#{total})  ")
                  end
                end
              rescue Exception => e
                @log.info("There is a problem loading row for index #{index} :#{row} because of #{e.message}")
                next
              end
            rescue Exception => e
              @log.info("There is a problem loading #{@file}: #{e.message}")
              next
            end 
          end
          @log.info("Loaded file #{@file} into database")
          FileUtils.rm(@file)
        end
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      @log.warn("Unable to process the data feed: #{@file} because #{e.message}")
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For starters, I'd break the script up into many more methods. If nothing else it'll avoid the "pyramid code" (all that nested indentation) you've got going on. But it should also make the code easier to understand, maintain and extend.

I'd also, as an overall approach, favor writing a file of `INSERT` statements, rather than inserting each row, one at a time. At least for testing, I'd highly recommend this. You can always read this file directly into mysql later. The point is that if, say, the first 2 rows get inserted fine, but the 3rd fails, you'll already have those first 2 row in the database, when you run the script again. And since the .xlsx files only get removed if *everything* works out, the same file may be imported several times - perhaps failing halfway several times - resulting in a bunch of doubled rows.

Speaking of files, I'd avoid completely removing the xlsx file once it's done. Probably better to move it or rename it, so you still have it, but it won't get read again. In general, just try to avoid destructive operations unless necessary.

Anyway, the code below is an attempt to break up your code. I haven't tried it, so don't just blindly run it or anything.

Moreover, I'm using RubyXL's `get_table` method here - I don't know if that's actually useful in your case. However, I imagine that the xlsx-files have a header row, since you always skip the first row. If those headers are sensical, you can use them to your advantage, and avoid the hard-coded (and opaque) column indices.

Some of the methods here have optional arguments that default to instance variables. I won't recommend that for production use; it's there for testing purposes. You can either make the arguments required, or you can remove the arguments, and rely on instance variables.

```
# Hash for translating xlsx columns to mysql columns
# The procs may not be necessary; get_table may handle conversion
COLUMN_TRANSLATIONS = {
  "Service"     => { column: "service",     proc: :to_s },
  "Impressions" => { column: "impressions", proc: :to_i },
  "Clicks"      => { column: "clicks",      proc: :to_i },
  "Cost"        => { column: "cost",        proc: :to_f },
  "Total"       => { column: "total",       proc: :to_f }
}.freeze

# Gets the relevant .xlsx-files
def xlsx_files(directory = @paid_adv_work_path)
  path = File.join(directory, "*(PPC)*.xlsx")
  files = Dir.glob(path)
  files.reject { |file| File.basename(file) =~ /^~/ }
end

# Use get_table to get structured data
def read_xlsx(file)
  workbook  = RubyXL::Parser.parse(file)
  worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0]
  worksheet.get_table(COLUMN_TRANSLATIONS.keys)[:table]
end

# Translate into a mysql-friendly format
def translate_table(table)
  table.map do |row|
    row.map do |column, value|
      lookup = COLUMN_TRANSLATIONS[name.to_s] # get_table uses symbol keys; we want strings
      value = value.send(lookup[:proc])
      [lookup[:column], value]
    end
  end
end

# Insert a row
def insert_rows(rows, connection = @db)
  columns = COLUMN_TRANSLATIONS.map { |name, info| info[:column] }
  rows.each do |row|
    columns = row.keys.join(", ")
    values  = row.values.map { |value| "'#{connection.escape(value)}'" }.join(", ")
    query = "INSERT INTO ppc (#{columns}) VALUES (#{values});"
    connection.query(query)
  end
end

# Put it together per-file
def import_xlsx_file(file, connection = @db)
  table = read_xlsx(file)
  rows  = translate_table(table)
  insert_rows(rows, connection)
end

# And all together now...
def import
  xlsx_files.each do |file|
    begin
      import_xlsx_file(file)
      # Handle file removal/renaming here
    rescue => e
      @log.info "Failed to import #{file}: #{e.message}"
    end
  end
end
```

An advantage of having the optional arguments is that you can swap out the database connection with a stand-in object, like:

```
class QueryLogger
  def initialize(logger)
    @logger = logger
  end

  def query(string)
    @logger.info(string)
  end
end
```

And try something like `import_xlsx_file(some_file, QueryLogger.new(@log))` to log the queries instead of actually running them on the server.

Comment: one detail: `rescue Exception => exc` is no good, should capture only `StandardError`, which is completely equivalent to `rescue => exc`.

Comment: @tokland Oops, you're right - amending the code. Thanks